# Formatar coluna de tabela pelo id utilizando jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como faço para formatar apenas a coluna que o usuário selecionar.
Para isso estou utilizando um Loop em PHP com o While. A cada lopp me retorna um id. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    var id_check = $(this).attr('id');  //recebe os valores do atributo id do botão clicado
    $("td id="+id_check).css("color", "red");
   }
   else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
     $("td id="+id_check).css("color", "green");
   }
 });
```

Não vou colocar o Loop do PHP por ser muito extenso, mas o princípio é que o `<input type=checkbox>` possui um id.

Comment: Só não entendi o que vc quer fazer no final. Coloca na pergunta seu html tb

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem certeza que os id's são únicos, você pode fazer assim:

```
$("#"+id_check).css("color", "red");
```

Comment: Dessa forma não funcionou. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.